# What is the known cheapest chemical solution to extract CO2 from air on industrial scale?

Tags: physical-chemistry, extraction

As far as I know, the cheapest non-chemical solution is: grow grass, and burn it. The resulting $\ce{CO2}$ is from the air. But I am interested on chemical industrial solutions now.

As far as I know, the main difficulty of the process is that the ratio of the $\ce{CO2}$ in the air is very low. Thus, extracting it means a large entropy difference.

My layman's intuition is that maybe some substance exists - probably an organic compound - which binds especially strongly to $\ce{CO2}$ and it is easily regenerated. One would pump air through it, and then regenerate it to get the $\ce{CO2}$ back. If such a compound exists, what is it?

The process should be powered by electrical energy only. Thus, solutions such as "buy gas, burn it, and you get much cheaper $\ce{CO2}$" are not acceptable.

On "cheapest" I understand, what is cheapest in industrial size, not in a laboratory? (for example, in a large chemical factory)

Comment: Surprisingly, the cheapest solution might be refrigeration. Water vapor will freeze out at $0\ ^\circ\mathrm{C}$ and the next major component of air to freeze out will be carbon dioxide at $-78\ ^\circ\mathrm{C}$.

Comment: @BenNorris The ratio of CO2 in air is 0.035%, what is the vapor pressure of -78% CO2? Ok, maybe there is an optimum which depends on the cost of the freezing (and the heat exchanger), where the extracted CO2/$ is maximal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, and such compounds are plenty. The cheapest are probably $\ce{NaOH}$, $\ce{Ca(OH)_2}$ and the like, but these are not easily regenerable. Then there are organic amines, like [monoethanolamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanolamine), which can do the same in a reversible manner. Indeed, they are used in [industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber#Amine_scrubbing).

Comment: This is right. Organic amines are what I've heard the most about for recovering CO2 from gas streams.